# how to remove extra stacklabel appearing on top in barchart(highcharts)?

Tags: highcharts

I am using stack labels in stacked bar charts(highcharts).I am facing an issue with stack labels, one extra label appear on top of chart at axis intersection. Can anyone please suggest why the extra stack label appears on top of axis at 0?

I could not find any answer related to this issue, is it a known issue in highcharts?

I am using following versions of highcharts

```
- Highcharts-3.0.4/js/highcharts.js
- Highcharts-3.0.4/js/modules/exporting.js
```

Please suggest, I am stuck with it.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your chart code in a fiddle?

Comment: I am not using static configuration, the whole chart loaded by using dynamic data. It is not feasible to recreate. I guess its problem with 3.0.4. It works well with 3.0.9 but I have to use 3.0.4 because many other issues arises with 3.0.9. Below I have posted the screenshot.

https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2735

Comment: I am using following code to enable it dynamically : charts[chart_num].yAxis[0].options.stackLabels.enabled = true;   charts[chart_num].yAxis[0].options.stackLabels.formatter = function() {   
           if(level == 2){           if(this.stack == 'current'){         if(typeof re_date[this.x] != "undefined"){                 var rel_date = Date.parse(re_date[this.x]);            if(isNaN(rel_date) == false){        return '<img src="/images/appimages/gp/checkmark.png"></img>';               }

Comment: Without any code it is not possibel to replicate / investigate issue. Seconodly I advice to update your files to the newest versions.

Comment: but with new versions, I am facing other issues like the context menu doesnot appear and subtitle doesnot take margins.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aWy6L/ here is fiddle for issue in 3.0.9

Comment: Both options are not supported in dynamic way as you have. you need to destroy and create new chart.